# While clicking on forget password directly from landing page getting error Url not found

Tags: mysql, spring, angular

When I start the project for the first time, I am getting 404 url not found error for forgot password. Once logged in and logout the application I am able to use forgot password and email will be sent to particular user. Is there any solution for this?

Using spring security , Angular 4.

```
`forgotPassword(Username: string) {
        console.log(Username);
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        let myParams = new URLSearchParams();
        myParams.set('Username', Username);
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, params: myParams });
        return this.http.get('/app/url/forgotpassword', options)
            .map(
            (response: Response) => {
                let data = response;
                console.log(data);
            });
    }`
```

Comment: Please post the code for routing and components you've written

Comment: i have added UserService.ts file in my question

Comment: @dijofrancis please update route configuration not the service.

Comment: we are getting 404 error in the above service call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved, there was a problem with SSL.